# odd-pages printed as left pages...why?

Tags: titles, page-numbering, printing

Sorry, I´m newbie to latex.

I´m using KOMA-Script Book as document class and two-sided document as page layout and I have the following problem: chapters do correctly start with their first page odd-numbered. BUT (and for me it´s a big BUT), as the title page (first page of the document) is the first page to be printed, the impact when printing the whole document is the following:

- chapters, although starting by an odd-numbered page, do start with their first page on the left-side (i.e. the first page of each chapter is on the back of the printed pages as you pile them).

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... As you are not providing any `MWE` of your code, it is difficult to give suggestion, do you try with the class file option `twoside`, i.e., \documentclass[twoside]{...}`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi `twoside` would allow the chapters to start on odd or even pages, but it wouldn't change the fact that odd-numbered pages should be on the right, not the left.  But I definitely agree a MWE would really help.

Comment: The `scrbook` does `twoside` by default so that's not the issue. Without the MWE, it's impossible to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks @MadyYuvi and Don, indeed the twoside option was not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without a working example, it's hard to diagnose, but I'm going to guess you're using a `titlepage` environment rather than `\maketitle` to generate your title page. If that's the case, it looks like there's a bug in the definition of the `titlepage` environment where it does a `\newpage` instead of `\cleardoublepage` in the `\end{titlepage}` command. Adding `\cleardoublepage` after `\end{titlepage}` should resolve the issue.

**Update**: Without a MWE, I'm unable to replicate the issue. The following produces the expected results without any special handling.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\chapter{Chapter}
Chapterpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: I´m using this:

Comment: I´m using maketitle plus lowertitleback after the front page: 

\lowertitleback{\textbf{Date}\smallskip{}
\\
DD.MM.AAAA\textbf{\frontmatter}}
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage{}

Your answer gave me the idea of trying without lowertitleback and then suddenly the whole document looks right and with the first page of chapters odd-numbered AND at the right. So thank you so much!

Anyway, do you have some idea of why lowertitleback has such impact? 

Thanks again.